# Не могу передать значения массива из одного класса в другой. C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть 2 библиотеки person.h и TXRIP.h
в библиотеке TXRIP.h есть геттер который возвращает значение массива ground [10][10]

```cpp
int get_ground()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                return ground[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

В другом классе другого .h файла у меня лежит масив pers[10][10]
и для него я написал сеттер функцию

```cpp
void set_pers(int a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                pers[i][j]=a;
                printf("%d\n",a);
            }
        }
    }
```

также в main() я вызываю функцию сеттер со значением геттера, но после проверки понял что он передаёт только нули.
main.cpp

```cpp
Karta karta_t; //Karta название класса
Person person_t; //Person название другого класса
person_t.set_pers(karta_t.get_ground());
```

В чём проблема?
Если что массив выглядит вот так

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Ну во-первых никаких классов я не вижу. Во-вторых, Ваша функция get выдает не массив а одно значение int. Цикл не выполняется. фактически эта функция выводит только значение ground[0][0]. Дальше Ваша функция set берет одно значение set и присваивает его всему массиву pers. Т.е. то Ваш код работает именно так как Вы и описали. Для передачи массивов нужно использовать соответствующие типы, например int[][] или int**

Answer (score 1):

Вызываем...

```
int get_ground()
{
```

Входим в первую итерацию, `i == 0`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
```

Входим во первую итерацию второго цикла, `j == 0`:

```
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
```

Возвращаем *из функции, **завершая этим ее работу***

```
            return ground[i][j];
```

Все, как написано. Можно было даже проще:

```
int get_ground() { return ground[0][0]; }
```

Как именно переписать — зависит от того, что именно вы хотите. Ведь сеттер-то у вас тоже загоняет *во все элементы одно и то же значение*.